# Replace characters with a number

Tags: r

sorry to bother you. I have a data.frame that contains items like:

> F1008Y
>   F1008Y
>   406_407insD
>   R1207*

I would like to replace all that items with "1". 
How this can be done?

Comment: Hi. I mean I want "F1008Y" to become 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ifelse`

```
DF <- read.table(text="F1008Y
F1008Y
406_407insD
R1207*
0
0", header=FALSE) # adding some 0

DF # this is your data.frame
           V1
1      F1008Y
2      F1008Y
3 406_407insD
4      R1207*
5           0
6           0

ifelse({df <- DF; df!=0}, df[,] <- 1, df[,] <- 0) # replacing
     V1
[1,]  1
[2,]  1
[3,]  1
[4,]  1
[5,]  0
[6,]  0

 # the original data.frame remains the same
 DF
           V1
1      F1008Y
2      F1008Y
3 406_407insD
4      R1207*
5           0
6           0
```

Comment: Hi Jiber, thank you so much. I forgot to write in my question that the data.frame contains "0" items too. So when I run your code, the "0" are replaced too. Instead they have to remain 0.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example that takes advantage of the fact that when you use `as.numeric` on a vector that has numbers and strings mixed together, the strings get converted to `NA`. I've added an extra column just for fun.

```
DF <- read.table(text="F1008Y
F1008Y
406_407insD
R1207*
0
0", header=FALSE)
DF$V2 <- DF$V1
DF.bak <- DF ## Backups are always nice
DF
#            V1          V2
# 1      F1008Y      F1008Y
# 2      F1008Y      F1008Y
# 3 406_407insD 406_407insD
# 4      R1207*      R1207*
# 5           0           0
# 6           0           0
## By default, the columns have been read in as factors. Convert to character
DF[sapply(DF, is.factor)] = lapply(DF[sapply(DF, is.factor)], as.character)
DF[is.na(sapply(DF, as.numeric))] <- 1
# Warning messages:
# 1: In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
# 2: In lapply(X = X, FUN = FUN, ...) : NAs introduced by coercion
DF
#   V1 V2
# 1  1  1
# 2  1  1
# 3  1  1
# 4  1  1
# 5  0  0
# 6  0  0
```